# How can I create three random integers which sum to a specific value? (Python)

Tags: python, random, integer, sum

Let's say bob = 6

I want to create 3 random integers that have a sum of 106 (100 + whatever bob's original integer is. It could be 10, but in this case, it's 6).

I've got:

```
from random import *
bob = 6
bob1 = (randint(0,100))
bob2 = (randint(0,100))
bob3 = (randint(0,100))
print bob1
print bob2
print bob3
```

I can generate integers, but how can I make sure the sum of them = 100 + original integer? (106 total). If the sum doesn't = 106, then I want the script to keep going until it makes 106.

Comment: What if `bob=201`? how long would you like your script keep going until it makes 301?

Comment: Hi gboffi, i'm keeping it simple for now, but yes, in theory I would like the script to handle any number. But for now, i'm just keeping it basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just calculate the third value:

```
from random import randint
bob = 6
bob1 = randint(0, 100)
bob2 = randint(0, min(100, 100 + bob - bob1))
bob3 = 100 + bob - bob1 - bob2
print bob1
print bob2
print bob3
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I wanted. I just had to add an extra ) closing bracket on line 4. But otherwise this seems perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The general approach to generate numbers that add up to a certain number is like this:

```
import random
bob = 6
numbers = sorted(random.sample(range(100+bob), 2))
bob1 = numbers[0]
bob2 = numbers[1] - numbers[0]
bob3 = 100 + bob - numbers[1]
```

It selects two cut points between `0` and `100 + bob` and assigns the numbers as illustrated:

[image]

This will also ensure all three numbers have the same distribution (simulated with 1m trials):

```
mean    34.700746   35.639730   35.659524
std     24.886456   24.862377   24.861724
```

As opposed to the numbers generated dependently:

```
mean    50.050665   27.863753   28.085582
std     29.141171   23.336316   23.552992
```

And their histograms:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
bob1 = (randint(0,100))
bob2 = (randint(0,(100-bob1)))
bob3 = 100 - (bob1 + bob2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general function that will always randomly generate 3 numbers in [0, n] that add to n; as the intermediate values are determined by `"bob"`'s initial value, we pass it this value and a target total number. The function returns a tuple of 3 numbers that together with bob-initial-value add up to the target:

```
import random

def three_numbers_to_n(bob, target):
    n = target - bob
    a = random.randrange(0, n+1)
    b = random.randrange(a, n+1) - a
    c = n - a - b
    return a, b, c

for _ in range(5):
    bob = 6
    result = three_numbers_to_n(bob, 106)
    print(bob, result, sum(result) + bob)
```

sample output:

```
6 (13, 3, 84) 106
6 (45, 49, 6) 106
6 (27, 2, 71) 106
6 (44, 18, 38) 106
6 (100, 0, 0) 106
```

If you wish, you could `random.shuffle(a, b, c)` before returning to remove the predictability that the first number is likely larger than the second likely larger than the 3rd.