# Random distribution of integers with fixed total

Tags: python, random, floating-accuracy

I'm trying to get a random distribution of N integers with total sum equal to K.

```
numbers = np.array(range(N))

for n in range(N):
    prob[n] = rd.randrange(10000)

sum = numpy.sum(prob)
prob = (prob / sum * K).astype(int)
```

The problem is that the result is not exactly equal to N because of float number approximation. For example N = 100 will yield a a total of about 95.

What is a pythonic solution to this problem?

Comment: What sort of distribution should the random numbers have?

Comment: How about: generate any random set of integers (of a size and distribution that you like) using your technique, and then adjust the last value to make the sum match?

Comment: @Phrogz any random distribution would work, what you suggest is not very elegant but doable

Comment: *Any* random-dist? Returning zeros only with the last number=N is *any* fixed random-dist too. Without more specifics it's hard to reason about the task. I'm not that sure if the above is an answer for this task.

Comment: I agree with @Phrogz, but was puzzling over the question, how should the OP determine the count of randoms before fudging the final one?  I guess it could be the desired total divided by the mean value - 1?  That will result in a sets of uniform max size.

Comment: @sasha I'm sorry, what I meant is that the probability function is not a strict requirement.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824129/how-can-i-create-three-random-integers-which-sum-to-a-specific-value-python/36824282#36824282

Comment: Your `n`s and `N`s seem a bit confused here. (E.g., when you do (prob / sum * n), the value of `n` will be `N-1` from the previous loop.) How many random numbers do you have, and what total should they sum to?

Comment: @Mark, corrected the code, thanks

Comment: So you want exactly `N` integers adding to `N`?

Comment: I think the comments here (and the pointers to possible dups that are more fully specified) should communicate to you that the question is under-constrained.

Comment: @Mark, now it's correct @ danh the technique described in both mentioned questions is what I was looking for

Comment: btw, I tried to answer to this question with a link to the already answered question to mark it as solved, but the answer was converted to comment for 'triviality'. I don't know how else to mark this as solved...